# How can i create a user Specific for network access in windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, permissions, network-shares, samba

This is my case. I have a shared folder in windows 10 and i want it to be password protected. Currently i have to enter my live account credentials to access that network share. But i don't want to share those information with other people who need to access my share.

What i need is to create a user just for network share access. I don't want that user to popup as a login choice on startup. Can i simply create a specific set of credentials for that share?

Comment: As currently configured if you share the folder with their user account, they wouldn't have to use your password to access the data, they would have to use their password.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Do what exactly?  You indicated you already performed the required steps to share the folder with other users.

Comment: How to authorize their credentials on my share?

Comment: You did that when you added the user to the list of users that could access the shared directory.

Comment: I didn't. That's the question. I want to let them use my share without giving my account information. I want to create a dummy account just to access the share. Just like in Linux.

Comment: You don't have to create a dummy account.  Share the folder, with their account, on their device.  This means they will have to authenticate as them, just like you have to autenticate your account, when you attempt to acces sit.